# The non-existence of non-principal ultrafilters in ZF

Tags: reference-request, logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, filters

In Hrbacek and Jech (1999, p.205), they point out that "it is known that the theorem [the extension of any filter to an ultrafilter] cannot be proved in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory alone." And in Jech (2000, p.81), he mentioned that "[i]t is known that the theorem [the Prime Ideal Theorem] cannot be proved without using the Axiom of Choice. However, it is also known that the Prime Ideal Theorem is weaker than the Axiom of Choice."

I am having a hard time finding a reference for the above claims. Can someone please give me some pointers (references) to, for instance, $\mathbf{ZF}\not\vdash \{\text{existence of non-principal ultrafilters}\}$? Thanks!

---

- Hrbacek, K. and Jech, T. J. (1999). Introduction to Set Theory. Marcel Dekker, New York, third edition.
- Jech, T. J. (2003). Set Theory. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, Heidelberg, New York, 3rd millennium ed, rev. and expanded edition.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211617/ultra-filter-and-axiom-of-choice

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to what Noah wrote, Jech "The Axiom of Choice" has a proofs, partial proofs, or problems with hints for the following:

1. In the first Cohen model, the axiom of [countable] choice fails; but the Boolean Prime Ideal theorem holds. Therefore every filter can be extended to an ultrafilter there.
2. There is a model of $\sf ZF$ in which there are no free ultrafilters on $\omega$. In the same model the Hahn-Banach theorem also fails (although Hahn-Banach is strictly weaker than the ultrafilter lemma).

   You can find the full proof in Halbeisen's "Combinatorial Set Theory" (whereas Jech gives this as an exercise with a hint).

These contain better exposition from a modern point of view, compared to papers from the 1960s.

---

Blass proved, as Noah pointed out, that it is consistent that every ultrafilter is principal. The proof is constructed from two parts:

1. Constructing a forcing extension where every filter on $\omega$ is principal, start from $L$.

   Proving that if there is no inner model with a measurable cardinal (e.g. if you start from $L$), then if there is no free ultrafilter on $\omega$, then there are no free ultrafilters on any well-orderable set.
2. Prove that if $W$ is the smallest class containing all the singletons and closed under well-ordered unions, and all ultrafilters on ordinals are principal, then all ultrafilters on sets in $W$ are principal.

   And that the model constructed in the very first step, is internally equal to $W$.

The paper itself is surprisingly short, too.

Answer (score 9):

See this mathoverflow question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59157/reference-request-independence-of-the-ultrafilter-lemma-from-zf, especially the answer by Andreas Blass.

Sol Feferman proved that $ZF$ does not prove that there is a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega$, in "Some applications of the notions of forcing and generic sets" http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm56/fm56129.pdf.

The stronger statement "$ZF$ does not prove that *any* infinite set carries a nonprincipal ultrafilter" was proved by Andreas Blass in "A model without ultrafilters."

The ultrafilter lemma was proved strictly weaker than full $AC$ by Halpern and Levy, in ""The Boolean prime ideal theorem does not imply the axiom of choice."

(Sadly, I can't find Blass or Halpern-Levy online.)

In general, the book "Consequences of the axiom of choice" by Rubin and Rubin and the accompanying website http://consequences.emich.edu/conseq.htm are invaluable for this sort of question.

Comment: This is very helpful. Let me look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a [link](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=TVi2AwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA83&dq=The+Boolean+prime+ideal+theorem+does+not+imply+the+axiom+of+choice&ots=LW6b7WNhP1&sig=8mizByFmOhkCJd6QdA_GJucip_M#v=onepage&q=The%20Boolean%20prime%20ideal%20theorem%20does%20not%20imply%20the%20axiom%20of%20choice&f=false) to Halpern-Levy.

Comment: Uhh... no. Cohen's first model satisfies $\sf BPI$ therefore there are many nonprincipal ultrafilters on $\omega$. Remember that at the day, generic extensions were often called "Cohen models".

Comment: @AsafKaragila I've removed that sentence. I'm surprised, though - how do you get a hereditarily symmetric name for an ultrafilter?

Comment: No. That is the heart and soul of the very difficult Halpern-Levy paper. If you trace their proof, you should find out how to define such name more explicitly.

Comment: I see, thanks Asaf! (This really isn't my area of experties :D)