# One can't construct ultrafilters

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, filters

In model theory, for the construction of an ultraproduct one needs the existence of an ultrafilter.

I heard that one can't construct an ultrafilter by hand, one cannot write it down, just merely knowing that one exists by using the axiom of choice. How is this meant? *Even if I give you a concrete base set, say $X=\mathbb N$, is it not possible to write down an ultrafilter on $X$?* (I just notice, that $U$ defined by $A\in U:\Longleftrightarrow 3\in A$ probably is an ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$, but it is a boring one, so my question should ask for *real* examples.)

Of course, up to now, my question is quite imprecise. Maybe one can formalize it like so: in ZF (without AC), is it possible to prove the existence of an ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$ which is non-principal?

What about other base sets, say finite ones? Can ZF prove the existence of an ultrafilter on a finite set?

Comment: This is an interesting situation.  An object proved to exist by ZFC but cannot be written down explicitly.  Example... a set that is not Lebesgue measurable.  Or a discontinuous linear functional on a Banach space.  A group isomorphism between additive groups $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$.  Many more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me first answer the last question. ZF can certainly prove existence of ultrafilters on (nonempty) finite sets, but it also proves all such ultrafilters are principal - indeed, such an ultrafilter $U$ must have finitely many elements, so we can take an intersection of all elements of $U$, and the result will be some one-element set $\{a\}$ and then $A\in U$ iff $a\in A$.

This means that we have to move to infinite sets to get interesting, nonprincipal ultrafilters. But it turns out that that ZF cannot prove that there is a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$. Indeed, it is known that ZF cannot prove that there is a nonprincipal ultrafilter on *any* set, i.e. it is consistent that *all* ultrafilters on *all* sets are principal! You can find references and more details in answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1321374/127263).